Apply parametric gate to quantum state in symbolic tensor representation
Suppose I am given a $n$-qubits statevector $|\psi\rangle$ and a single-qubit parametric gate $G_i(\theta)$ to be applied on qubit $i$. I want to implement from scratch a Python function to apply the parametric gate (using its symbolic representation) to the quantum state (written as a $n$-dim symbolic tensor) and return the result.
Let's consider an explicit example: take $|\psi\rangle = |000\rangle$ and $G_i(\theta) = RX_i(\theta)$ where the $X$-axis rotation gate is defined as
$$
RX(\theta) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta/2) & -i \sin(\theta/2)\\
-i \sin(\theta/2) & \cos(\theta/2)\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
A possible working implementation, based on numpy multi-dimensional arrays, would be the following:
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, cos, sin, I

num_qubits = 3
shape = (2,) * num_qubits
psi = np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]).reshape(shape)

theta = Symbol('t')
rx = np.array([[cos(theta/2), -I*sin(theta/2)],
               [-I*sin(theta/2), cos(theta/2)]])

def apply_1q_gate(state, gate, i):
    td = np.tensordot(gate, state, axes=(1, 0))
    reverse = list(range(len(state.shape)))[::-1]
    result = np.moveaxis(td, 0, i).transpose(*reverse)
    return result

However, this function operates using numpy arrays with dtype=object, which is extremely unnatural and inefficient since it is optimized for numerical computation. I was wandering whether it is possible to implement an equivalent function working for instance with sympy symbolic expressions.
NOTE: the sympy.tensor.array module (see here) may be useful!

A pure sympy solution would be:
from sympy import Symbol, cos, sin, I
from sympy import eye, Matrix
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct

num_qubits = 3
i = 1 #index of qubit where RX is applied

# initial state
psiList = [1] + [0] * (2**num_qubits - 1)
psi = Matrix(psiList)

# single qubit RX gate
theta = Symbol('t')
rx = Matrix([[cos(theta/2), -I*sin(theta/2)],
             [-I*sin(theta/2), cos(theta/2)]])

# single qubit identity gate
opI = eye(2)

# create a list of single qubit identity gates and the single qubit RX gate at position i
ops = [opI] * num_qubits
ops[i] = rx

# tensor product of these single qubit gates
rxFull = TensorProduct(*ops)

# apply this gate to the initial state
rxFull * psi

The output of this is
Matrix([[cos(t/2)], [0], [-I*sin(t/2)], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]])


Hi @Mathias and thanks for the answer!
Your solution works fine but it's not based on the tensor representation of the quantum state and thus it would require to compute the $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix for each single gate you want to apply and perform the full matrix-vector multiplication. This is very inefficient and scales exponentially with the number of qubits $n$.
